# Testing layer for Has Selection using fidSet not working as expected

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.4

I am using ArGIS Desktop Standard 10.4.1 with Python 2.7.11, and am a S elf-taught Python scripter.

I've researched this extensively but there doesn't appear to be anything newer than 2014.

I am trying to test if a feature layer has a selection or not. I'm doing this via my own python script in ArcToolbox.

Essentially what is happening is that the length of **len(arcpy.Describe(lyr).fidSet.split(";"))** when no features are selected is returning 1. Prior posts on this subject indicate that it should return 0. Below is some very simple code:

```
lyr = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)    # parameter is a feature layer

arcpy.AddMessage(len(arcpy.Describe(lyr).fidSet.split(";")))
arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.Describe(lyr).fidSet.split(";"))

if len(arcpy.Describe(lyr).fidSet.split(";")) > 0:
    arcpy.AddMessage("Has Selection")
else:
    arcpy.AddMessage("No Selection")
```

If zero feature are selected this returns

```
1
[u'']
Has Selection
```

If one feature is selected it returns

```
1
[u'5']
Has Selection
```

If more than one feature is selected it returns

```
9
[u'1', u' 2', u' 3', u' 4', u' 5', u' 6', u' 7', u' 8', u' 9']
Has Selection
```

I've tried testing the returned string with **is None** and also putting **not** in front of the length statement, but those still return **Has Selection** when no features are selected.

Answer (score 2):

As you know, FIDSet returns a list of ID in a string, separated with a semi-colon.

Your problem is not really a arcpy problem, but it is due to the fact that .split(delimiter) returns a non empty list (see [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645083/when-splitting-an-empty-string-in-python-why-does-split-return-an-empty-list) for more details).

So, in fact, you should simplify your test: test for FIDSet==0 and it will be tell you when there are no selected elements.

```
if len(arcpy.Describe(lyr).fidSet) == 0: # alternatively: if arcpy.Describe(lyr).fidSet =='' :
    print "nothing selected"
else:
    print "{} elements selected".format(len(arcpy.Describe(lyr).fidSet.split(";"))
```

Answer (score 2):

`arcpy.Describe (lyr).FIDSet` returns an empty string (`''`) when no selection is present. Empty strings return `False` in a logic test. Thus, use:

```
if arcpy.Describe (lyr).FIDSet:
    #selection
else:
    #no selection
```

[image]

---

[image]